# Playing mp4 in Layout android

Tags: android, video, layout

I have an activity in which I want to play a video from "raw" folder in it's own layout,(when the app starts) not in any default app.

The layout -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="VIDEO PLAYER"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: from above code whats the error ?

Comment: video view u hv writeen ..u would hv also wrriten code to play it..isnt it?

Comment: ok so basically it a videoView and u wanna play it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
     VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.splash);
     videoview.setVideoURI(uri); videoview.start();
```